# Install LaTeX on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11)

Tags: installing, mactex, filesystem-access

How do I install MacTex or another LaTeX distribution?

Even after installation, LaTeX commands like `latex`, `pdftex` or `lualatex` are not found, and `/usr/texbin/` doesn't exist.

Even worse, commands like `sudo mkdir -p /usr/texbin` return "`permission denied`"

Comment: You did see on the MacTeX list that this has been addressed for the release version of TL'15, I assume?

Comment: No, I didn't. I fixed my issue literally minutes before the new release and didn't check for an update since.

Comment: In general we tend not to take questions on pre-release versions of software. Normally, of course, that's from the 'TeX end' where feedback from people here might influence the code. Whilst that's less likely with an OS, the same position might seem reasonable.

Comment: Further to my earlier comment, see the 'PS' in http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.macosx/47074 and in particular the statement about behaviour on _El Capitan_.

Comment: The help center allows questions about "Distributions like ... MacTeX". The question is relevant to many users, and this forum is the most suitable place to find help. I can't see why the question was marked "off-topic", except perhaps that some people don't like Apple.

Comment: @JairoBochi My thought exactly: if you happen to have the same issue while installing MacTeX, regardless of the OS you're running, you seek help from similar user on this forum. Even if MacTeX adapts to it later, you at least have a temporary solution.

Comment: After considerable struggling, I realized that for my installation, the path to the TeX binaries was not ...Contents/Programs/texbin. It was ...Contents/Programs/i386. I seem to be up and running now after creating a symbolic link with this Terminal command: sudo ln -fhs Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/i386 /Library/TeX/texbin

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The new Mac OS comes with a feature named "*rootless*" that disallows modification of important system files, even by the root user.

However, LaTeX installation requires access to the `/usr/texbin` folder, at least as an alias, and it is protected by Mac OS.

**There are two solutions:**

### 1) Disable the rootless feature

To disable the rootless feature at boot, run this command:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0 kext-dev-mode=1"
```

Reboot, and then run:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin /usr/texbin
```

if you already installed LaTeX from MacTex

### 2) Edit your `$PATH`

If you don't want to disable the rootless feature, you can just modify your `$PATH` to point to the location of your LaTeX installation.

For MacTex, files are located under `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin`, so the following command in your `.bash_profile` should work:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin
```

Comment: See http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.macosx/47074 Substitute `/usr/texbin` in the PATH with `/Library/TeX/texbin`

Comment: @Johannes_B Even the mactex installer? I don't remember having that ability, though I haven't tested much on mac

Comment: @daleif I just assumed it would be the same, i actually never used a mac. I deleted my comment just in case it is false information.

Comment: The Mactex installer is quite different. Basically it installs TL as a giant blob. Fastest installation around. Does not install all the individual packages one by one like the rest of us is used to.

Comment: Leaving aside whether this question is proper, I can confirm the second solution works fine. I use a build-script and set my PATH within that script rather than in the .bash_profile

Comment: ^ Note that the above method for "disabling rootless" has already been deprecated.  The newest official method (as of Sep 2, 2015 at least) is to restart your mac while holding `Cmd` + `s`.  This will boot into the recovery partition.  Once loaded, go to the menu at the top of the screen and select "Security Configuration".  This will open a dialogue box with only one checkbox that allows you to disable "System Integrity Protection".

Comment: While I'm at it... know that once you have rebooted, you can then add or remove the `restricted` flag to various files.  The `restricted` flag prevents the file (or directory) from being modified when System Integrity Protection is enabled.  To add the flag, run `chflags restricted file`.  To remove, run `chflags norestricted file`.  To see the flags in a directory run `ls -lO` (that's lowercase "ell" and uppercase "oh").  I'm sick of Googling stuff and not finding everything I need in one spot, so future Googlers wondering about SIP, there ya' go.

Comment: @Nick Thanks! Could you edit my answer to add your findings?

Comment: For people using LaTeXian, open Preferences, click on the Preview tab, and update "Folder for TeX installation" by clicking "Browse..." and opening the folder listed above: `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin`.

Comment: This failed for me because my binaries were not in the folder mentioned here. They were in a folder named i386, not texbin. I seem to be up and running after creating a symbolic link with this Terminal command: sudo ln -fhs Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/i386 /Library/TeX/texbin

Answer (score -3):

**Mac OS X El Capitan is not for public consumption**

1. This is a beta release, and not public at this point (i.e., you likely signed an NDA to get it)
2. All features are subject to change, and mucking around in nvram is inadvisable unless you really know what you're doing

A corollary to my second point: if you know what you're doing, you should ask on Apple's private forums or come up with your own workaround, because it's not a hard problem to solve.

Comment: I thought from what I'd seen the release was (relatively) accessible at this stage

Comment: This is not an answer dealing with the question, this is basically a disclaimer. Why didn't you add it to my answer?

Comment: @LaX As we are talking about _pre-release_ software it's as good an answer as any. Indeed, the question might well be closed as in general we take the line that pre-release or other testing versions are off-topic.

Comment: @JosephWright I'll argue that while this is indeed a pre-release software that is subject to change, this is the issue with installation that matters. The fact that Mac OS 10.11 is pre-release isn't relevant to TeX

Comment: Added as a separate answer to make it more obvious that I think the question should be closed. @JosephWright there will supposedly be a public beta in July; AFAIK at present it's limited to paying developers and seed testers under NDA. If I'm wrong on that last, I'd be happy to delete this answer.

Comment: This answer is outdated and should better be deleted.