# TexShop problem after OSX upgrade

Tags: mactex, texshop

After updating the OSX in my mac from Yosemite to El Capitan, I am not being able to compile any latex file in TexShop. I downloaded and reinstalled MacTex package but still get the error "/usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. Perhaps TeXLive was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade". I think the path to the TexLive might not have been properly configured during installation but am not being able to retrieve the path. Any comment or suggestion will be much appreciated.

More info: I tried to change the path solution also as suggested in [Install LaTeX on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249966/install-latex-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan-10-11), but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Welcome! You probably need to update TeXShop. Not only does `/usr/texbin/pdflatex` not exist on your system, I think that it cannot exist on your system because Apple have decided that they get to decide what goes in `/usr` and you don't. (You may think it is your machine - Apple know better.) Just [follow these instructions](https://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html).

Comment: Which version of MacTeX do you have?