# Is it safe to reinstall MacTex after upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan

Tags: installing, mactex, mac, knitr

I was using MacTex on OSX 10.10 (Yosemite).  I upgraded to OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) and now I get the error "No TeX installation detected" trying to compile a latex document using knitr.

I saw the writeup about this issue [here](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) and some fixes like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249967/38830), but I was wondering if I could just install the latest version of MacTex or if that would create any problems?

Comment: Could downvoters please leave a comment explaining what's wrong with this question?

Comment: @IanThompson OP asked if it was "safe" to reinstall MacTeX. Presumably this means something to him, but it's unclear to me, particularly in relation to the knitr error posed. He also linked to the MacTeX page which explicitly talks about installing MacTeX on El Capitan and has a document describing path changes necessary to use it.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell --- fair enough, but I would ask for clarification before downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this, I reinstalled MacTex and everything worked as expected.

Comment: How did you do that?