# MacTex 2015 + sublime Text + EI Captain, compile error

Tags: mactex, sublime-text

When I migrate my macbook from Yosemite to EI Captain. Compile latex using Sublime Text 3 + LatexTools can not work. So I reinstall MacTex 2015 and add /Library/Tex/texbin to path. But it still not work. These are the error messages while I compile a .tex file which is good on Yosemite. Besides these error messages there are a lot of warnings like

```
"/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/.tex:19009: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `^^@^^@^^@^^@^^..."
```

Anyone know the mean of the strange number "19009".

This is the line where all error happen.

```
\int_const:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D } 

SimpleBuilder: pdflatex run 1; done.
```

Errors:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: Missing number, treated as zero. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: Missing number, treated as zero. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: You can't use `\numexpr' in vertical mode. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: Missing number, treated as zero. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: Missing number, treated as zero. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: Missing number, treated as zero. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: You can't use `\numexpr' in vertical mode. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: Missing $ inserted. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex:19009: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/.tex:19009: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]. [...st:Nn \c_sys_month_int { \tex_month:D }]
```

Comment: Please search this side for other el capitan questions There you will find your solution!  For example possible duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273873/whats-happening-with-my-path-after-upgrade-to-el-capitan ?

Comment: After reinstalling mactex, did you update it? Remember, mactex is a slice in time, it needs to be updated afterwards. If that does not work, we will need a full minimal example so we can test whether it compiles on our systems