# MacTex - How to compile via command line?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, mactex

I'm new to LaTeX/TeX and recently installed `MacTeX` on my MacBook. Everything seems to work fine (I'm able to create and typeset files with *TeXShop*).

Now I want to compile some files via command line and read that I need to change into the projects directory and execute `pdflatex my_file.tex`. Sadly `MacTeX` doesn't seem to ship `pdflatex`. `which pdflatex` returns nothing.

Should `pdflatex` be included in `MacTeX` and my installation is broken? 
I already reinstalled `MacTeX` and checked the MD5 hash to verify that I have the right `MacTeX` installer...

What can I do to compile my *.tex*-files?

Comment: If MacTeX is installed correctly it does add all of the stuff to the path. Exactly which version did you install, which MacOS version do you have and have you updated it after installing MacTeX?

Comment: Under MacTeX2016, `pdflatex` is not a full-fledged file in the normal sense of the word "file", but "merely" a so-called symbolic link to the file `pdftex`, which is located in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin`. You should get a help menu type-out if you type `pdflatex --help` at a command prompt.

Comment: @JosephWright I have MacOS Sierra installed. I installed new latest version of MacTeX (04 June 2016) and haven't updated MacOS/MacTeX since.

Comment: @Herickson Sierra is pre-release: I suspect 'all bets are off'!

Comment: @Mico `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin` exists, but `pdflatex --help` isn't a command. Seems like the symbolic link is missing.

Comment: @JosephWright So nothing I can do at the moment?

Comment: @Herickson For pre-release we normally say it's off-topic _here_ but to ask the appropriate devs: in this case the MacTeX mailing list seems most reasonable.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` return (from the command line)? And what about `ls /etc/paths.d`?

Comment: @JosephWright Alright thank you really much. I'll delete this question then.

Comment: @egreg `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: @Herickson What does `ls /etc/paths.d` return?

Comment: What do you mean, "`pdflatex --help` isn't a command"?

Comment: @egreg `/etc/paths.d` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Mico The terminal doesn't recognise `pdflatex` as a command.

Comment: You can always use `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex --help`. Not a solution, but possibly useful for now.

Comment: @Herickson Then this question should go to the mailing list

Comment: @Mico But `which pdflatex` should still return a result if `pdflatex` is in PATH. Even if it is a symbolic link. (Indeed, even if it is a broken link.)

Comment: @egreg I'm not in the mailing list and don't really know how to report this, but I'm willing to give detailed information if necessary.

Comment: @cfr Yeah, that'll work for now I guess. Hoping to get an answer from a dev.

Comment: Since I don't have Sierra installed I can't comment on any changes, but perhaps my answer to this question [After migration to MacOSX 10.11 “El Capitan”, how to run simple utilities such as “texdoc” and “kpsewhich”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270485/2693) might be of help.

Comment: I am running MacOS Sierra successfully with LaTeX on one of my computers, and cannot recall having any issues with it, but that could possibly be because I already had it installed prior to upgrading to beta-OS. Anyway, i think this could be of help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249966/install-latex-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan-10-11

Comment: @RunarTrollet The question you link to deals with pre-release El Capitan. But the OP has installed TL 2016 which works without any trouble on that OS (and knowing a bit about the build process for MacTeX probably works with Sierra too.) So I don't think that's the solution to the problem.

Comment: What do `which pdflatex` and `echo $PATH` return? Do you set a PATH in your ~/.profile (or ~/.bash_profile)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45342/discussion-on-question-by-herickson-mactex-how-to-compile-via-command-line).

Comment: Have you opened a new terminal window since you installed MacTex? Stupid, but for me that was the issue. MacTex sets its paths in `/etc/paths.d`, so if you don't want to close your terminal window you can also run `eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it concerns a beta version of an OS which was fully released more than a year ago.

Answer (score 2):

I use

> xelatex

and it works perfectly fine for me.

For instance, use the below command to compile your tex file and generate the pdf:

```
xelatex --interaction=batchmode file_name.tex 2>&1 > /dev/null;open file_name.pdf
```

Remove the

> 2>&1 > /dev/null

part if you want to see the error messages.I am okay with them not being there.